# Error when launching VBox 4 on redhat 6 : /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6)

Tags: redhat, glibc, libstdc++

I want to launch VBox4 on redhat 6, however I get this error :

> version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6)

I verified that GLIBC_2.14 is installed on my system.

I don't know what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Someone (possibly you) has replaced the file `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` with a corrupted version that is incompatible with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.  You can restore the official version if you run this command as root:

```
# yum reinstall /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

You need to install a version of “VBox 4” which has been ported to Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, otherwise it will not work.  In general, it is not possible to take some program that has been built on a current GNU/Linux distribution and run it on a much older distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I don't understand the second part, I tried to install VBox6 that doesn't work , so I install VBox4 or I must install much older version ?

Comment: You mentioned “VBox 4” in the title of the question, so I assumed that this is what you were trying to install. Whatever it is, you need software that is compatible with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.

Comment: And how I know wich compatible with Red Hat Entreprise Linux 6 ? I want to try to install VMware or VBox . Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with those products. Have you tried the [virtualization solution that comes with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/virtualization_host_configuration_and_guest_installation_guide/)?